# Saving data to a different database table using Cakephp model::save()

Tags: cakephp

I am a newbie to cakephp and could really use some help and suggestions!

the application I am working with currently interacts with two databases, both databases have more or less a similar schema and table structure, I have to save some information in both databases, so i have this table say "employee_information" in both databases, both tables have a set of common fields (first_name, last_name, birthday, gender etc) and some other fields specific to that database.
now i have to save some information into the other database using cakephp model::save() method, previously I was normally switching data source and would use sql INSERT to do this and it was working fine, but now i really would like using cakephp conventional methods to do this, reason is that i think i am missing a great deal by not using cake's own methods ( data sanitizing in my case)
i had tried switching data source and using model::save(), the method did not work, though it did not log any errors, but also did not add any record into the database.

// using following snippet in the model to save.

`$this->setDataSource('secondary_database');`
`$this->save($this->data);`
`$this->setDataSource('primary_database');`

Any ideas or suggestions would be highly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: `$this->useTable = 'secondary_table';` http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/model-attributes.html#usetable. PS: you are asking for "different database table", do you want to use another "database", or another "table" within the SAME database?

Comment: I need to save data to another database, the tables in both databases have a same name and similar fields except for some additional fields specific to the db.

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there, but you need to setup two db configs and select them with [useDbConfig](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/model-attributes.html#usedbconfig)

For example:

```
$this->User->save($this->data); //Saves data to default (first) database
$this->User->useDbConfig('second'); //Selects second database for next uses
$this->User->save($this->data); //Saves data to second database too

//$this->User->useDbConfig('default'); //Not needed unless you want to do staff with the default database again later in the same code.
```

But if I'd need to save different fields in each DB, then I'd go with different models.

Answer (score 0):

Setting custom table for the controller after switching data source worked for me. (http://api.cakephp.org/1.3/class-Model.html#_setSource)

`$this->User->setDataSource('secondary_database');`
`$this->User->setSource('secondary_database_table');`
`$this->User->save($this->data,array(
            'validate' => true,
            'fieldList' => $fieldList // specific fields that needs to be updated.
));`